# I made a mistake when I was deploying projects with gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, flask-script

### When I use gunicorn to deploy the project, I can't find the module. When I use the test environment it is normal.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
        worker.init_process()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
        self.load_wsgi()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
        self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
        self.callable = self.load()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
        return self.load_wsgiapp()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
        return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
        __import__(module)
      File "/home/iHome_Flask/ihome_pyhon02/manage.py", line 4, in <module>
        from flask_script import Manager
    ImportError: No module named flask_script
    [2018-05-23 09:15:46 +0000] [29933] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 29933)
    [2018-05-23 09:15:46 +0000] [29928] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
    [2018-05-23 09:15:46 +0000] [29928] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
    (flask_py2) [root@iZbp1bvf97jli08phztpplZ ihome_pyhon02]# vim manage.py
```

Comment: The operating system is centOS 7.2

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that flask_script is installed as part of your global environment and not as part of your virtual environment.
Can you do a `pip show Flask-Script`?

Comment: I use pip freeze to query all modules in the virtual environment

```Name: Flask-Script
Version: 2.0.5
Summary: Scripting support for Flask
Home-page: http://github.com/smurfix/flask-script
Author: Dan Jacob
Author-email: danjac354@gmail.com
License: BSD
Location: /root/home/.virtualenvs/flask_py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: Flask
Required-by: ```

Comment: So your gunicorn is using your os' python environment `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ `
but flask-script is installed as part of your virtual environment?
`/root/home/.virtualenvs/flask_py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages`
Try it with both in the same environment

Comment: I uninstalled gunicorn in a formal environment and solved this problem.  
 : P